# Function call to memoization (with multiple parameters)

Tags: haskell

I would like to use memoization on a function with multiple different parameters

```
function :: (Int, Int) -> [[Int]] -> Int
```

What I tried so far:

```
function :: (Int, Int) -> [[Int]] -> Int
function (s, d) matrix = inner (s, d) matrix 
  where  
    inner (i, 0) g = g !! (i-1) !! (0)
    inner (i, k) g = maximum [memo ! ((i, k-1), g)
                             ,
                              memo ! ((i-1, k), g)
                             ]
    memo = listArray bounds
                [inner (i,k) g | ((i,k), g) <- Data.Array.range bounds]
    bounds = ( ((1,1), [[1,1]]), ((n,n), [[n,n]]) )
```

Still, it is not working as expected - the message I receive is:

> No instance for (Data.Array.Ix [[Int]]) arising from a use of ‘!’

Comment: Could you please create a test case, that is a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Memoizing a function taking an argument of type `[[Int]]` is unusual, and the array-based approach you are trying to use probably won't work. The error message is telling you that you can't use a `[[Int]]` as an index of the array. Perhaps you could use a `Data.Map` instead, but I don't know what to recommend in this case.

Comment: Making use of `(!!)` will probably result in a lot of overhead: `!! k`, works in *O(k)*, so for large `k`, this will take significant time.

Comment: Please explain what this code is supposed to do (pseudocode, specifications, examples...). I doublt you actually want to memoise on keys of type `[[Int]]` there.

Comment: Basically, the code is :    
    inner (i, 0) g = g !! (i-1) !! (0)
    inner (i, k) g = maximum [inner ((i, k-1), g)
                             ,
                              inner((i-1, k), g)
                             ]                                                                                        , without memoization. I would like to store the result of :  inner((i-1, k), g / [inner ((i, k-1), g in an array, using memoization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I happen to know that there's an [Data.Function.Memoize](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/memoize-0.8.1/docs/Data-Function-Memoize.html#t:Memoizable) package that will definitely make this whole thing easier.

In your case, I would use the `memoize2` function in this package with type signature

```
memoize2 :: (Memoizable a, Memoizable b) => (a -> b -> v) -> a -> b -> v
```

with `a = (Int, Int), b = [[Int]]`. The following instances would convince you that the type constraint is satisfied:

```
Memoizable Int
Memoizable a => Memoizable [a]
(Memoizable a, Memoizable b) => Memoizable (a, b)
```

Caveat note: though I have some good impression with this package, it does not seem very portable or reliable (if you're to build real things with it). The following statement can be found on its Hackage page:

> Note that most memoization in this style relies on assumptions about the implementation of non-strictness (as laziness) that are not guaranteed by the semantics. However, it *appears* to work.

Comment: Thank you. Fortunately, I solved the problem without this package.